# Changing an item in a list with a text document

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, tkinter

I have a problem where i'm running a function that should check through the lines in the text document, find the username that matches, and chagne the 2nd sintem in the list with each line (its a password reset program). The text document normally looks like this:

```
test test
username password
hello hi
```

This is the code i've tried. reset_username was taken when logging in.(I've also included the login function for example)

password change function:

```
def password_change():
    for _ in open('info.txt', 'r').readlines():
        login_info = _.split()
        if reset_username == login_info[0]:
            login_info[1] = [password_reenter_txt.get()]
            menu_window()
```

Login function:

```
def txt_file_log_in():

    try:
        for _ in open('info.txt', 'r').readlines():
            login_info = _.split() #split on the space made and store result with 2 strings
            if username_enter_txt.get() == login_info[0] and password_enter_txt.get() == login_info[1]:
                password_fault_report.configure(text='User name and Password Correct')

                global reset_username
                reset_username = username_enter_txt.get()

                messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'You have successfully logged in!')#pop up window informing user for sign up.
                login_window.destroy()
                final_window()

        password_fault_report.configure(text='User name or password incorrect,')

    except:
        password_fault_report.configure(text='No accounts found, you need to sign in first...')
```

The error i'm having is that it will run the function and run the menu window, however it doesn't change the document at all.

I am a beginner in tk, python so it could be a very stupid mistake so sorry. Also if iv'e made a mistake in the post, also let me know :)

Comment: You issue is not tkinter related. You only ever use `r` to read the data but never `w` write the data to the file. You are also missing the `close()` statement at the end of your function. You need to specify `close()` after `open()` or use `with open()` instead as it closes automatically when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `'r'` in an open statement allows to your "READ ONLY" the file. In order to write to the file you want to use `'w'` but keep in mind this will write the file and delete everything that was there before so we want to make sure we write everything back to the file.

We can accomplish this by using a list to store all values and updated as needed.

Example code:

```
def password_change(reset_username, password_reenter_txt):
    # Create empty list to hold file data.
    login_info = []
    with open('some_file', 'r') as data:
        for _ in data.readlines():
            login_info.append(_.split())
    print(login_info)
    # Check values in list and update if condition true.
    for sub_list in login_info:
        if len(sub_list) > 0:
            if reset_username == sub_list[0]:
                sub_list[1] = password_reenter_txt

    # write new values of list to file if previous condition met.
    with open('some_file', 'w') as data:
        for sub_list in login_info:
            if len(sub_list) > 0:
                data.write('{} {}\n'.format(sub_list[0], sub_list[1]))


for i in range(9):
    password_change('name' + str(i+1), 'pass')

# Check new values in file.
with open('some_file', 'r') as data:
    for _ in data.readlines():
        print(_.strip('\n'))
```

Test file data used:

```
name1 pass1
name2 pass1
name3 pass1
name4 pass1
name5 pass1
name6 pass1
name7 pass1
name8 pass1
name9 pass1
```

Results:

```
name1 new_pass
name2 new_pass
name3 new_pass
name4 new_pass
name5 new_pass
name6 new_pass
name7 new_pass
name8 new_pass
name9 new_pass
```

Comment: Hi ive had 2 days off the computer as i've been away with family and got back to my project. I'm having problems with running the code now. run I test it, it can only change the password for the user on the first line on the file, if i try reset that password for an accounts lower down on the file, it just removes the whole line down to the first one.

Comment: @AndyPaling I will take a look but the logic appears to be correct.

Comment: @AndyPaling asside for an index error if your file happens to have a blank line in it the code works on all usernames without issues on my end.

Comment: @AndyPaling I updated my example. It was working on my end but the indention of the `with open` used to write the file was indented in to far so maybe that will fix the problem for you.

Comment: Works better than before. However when I tried to reset the 3 user (third line txt file) when there were 5 accounts on the file, it reset the username for the 3rd account all good, except it removed the 4th and 5th account. When i tested it with 2 users set and changed the first user I had no problem so have no clue whats going wrong.

Comment: @AndyPaling did you copy my exact example or did you modify it?

Comment: ahh god, very sorry, I messed up with changing some of the varibale names.... Very sorry to waste you time all works now so thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You're reading your data from a file, then modifying the data **in memory**, but you never write it back to the file.